# Kate - работа с удалёнными файлами Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ssh

Вариант, который я знаю, мне не подходит:
После настройки ssh можно запустить kate напрямую из сервера. Минус такого редактирования в том, что он более медленный, и открывает за раз только один файл.

```
ssh -Y -С serverIP "kate /home/user/mail/main.rb"
```

Мне нужно, чтобы выглядело так же, но при этом сама программа должна запускаться с клиента.

Как работать с файлами через ssh или на крайний случай ftp, минуя дополнительные приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да все просто!

Файл -> Открыть -> Настройки -> Показывать панель быстрого доступа.

На "панели быстрого доступа", которая появится в том же диалоговом окне "Открыть" - правой кнопкой и выбрать "Добавить точку входа".

Откроется вот такое диалоговое окно:

[image]

Заполняете все поля нужными параметрами - и работайте с удаленным сервером

Comment: у меня ошибку выдаёт: Could not connect to host server: Timed out trying to connect to remote host

Comment: стоит заметить, что я на фтп попадаю без пароля, настроил ключи и захожу командой ssh server, логины и пароли для ssh и ftp едины

Comment: поправил. Для меня нужно вводить команду:

sftp://server

Comment: ну да - у каждого могут быть какие-то частности.

Answer (score 1):

Можно отвязаться от KDE и вместо совета выше использовать sshfs.

1. Устанавливаете sshfs (sudo apt-get install sshfs/emerge sshfs/yum install sshfs в зависимости от дистрибутива).
2. Монтируете по sshfs удаленную директорию к себе в домашнюю(или куда вам удобней).
3. Работаете с удаленной директорией, как с локальной.